# How to call TextWatcher from Class

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have a hint text and Normal text on a `EditText` field, I have specified different `Font-Size`, `Font-Color`, `Font-Name` for both. I have put that in my `ActivityClass` , and its working fine. I have around `10 Edit Text` fields, So it will be very odd if i add the `Textwatcher` for all, and doing the same stuff again and again. So i decided to create a class and put `TextWatcher` there.

But after adding that, it stops working. Its not changing the text color, Kindly guide me how to achieve this through `class`

```
public class FormTextCosmetics {

 public void changeHintText(final EditText editText){

        hintFontColor= context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white);
        normalFontColor= context.getResources().getColor(R.color.grayCheckoutFont);


        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(s.length() > 0){
                    editText.setTextSize(normalTextSize);
                    editText.setTypeface(Typeface.create(normalFontFamily, Typeface.NORMAL));
                    editText.setTextColor(normalFontColor);
                    editText.setAlpha(1);
                }else{
                    editText.setTextSize(hintFontSize);
                    editText.setTypeface(Typeface.create(hintFontFamily, Typeface.NORMAL));
                    editText.setTextColor(hintFontColor);
                    editText.setAlpha(0.52f);
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

**Main Activity Class**

```
FormTextCosmetics formTextCosmetics= new FormTextCosmetics(this);
formTextCosmetics.changeHintText(etName);
```

I have also tried to put above code in another `Textwatcher`, but it also not effecting the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `editText` is not 'aware' that it should call your class whenever something changes in it.
You should do it this way - your class should implement `TextWatcher`:

```
public class FormTextCosmetics implements TextWatcher {
    //Your code goes here
}
```

And then you use it like this -

```
etName.addTextChangedListener(new FormTextCosmetics());
```

Now the `editText` will call your class whenever something happens in it's text.